# Drop Down Menu shifting, only in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I have a simple drop down menu using HTML and CSS only.  The odd thing is, when I preview locally across all browsers it works fine.  When I upload to a webserver OR view via a network drive (stored there temporarily) all is well EXCEPT in Internet explorer where it shifts the submenus, making it impossible to click.  Guess i'm confused why this is working locally...  Here is code:

HTML:

```
<div id="nav"> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="Main1.htm">Main1</a> 
        <ul> 
        <li><a href="Submenu1.htm">Submenu1a</a> 
                <ul> 
                <li><a href="Submenu2a.htm">Submenu2</a></li> 
                <li><a href="Submenu2b.htm">Submenu2b</a></li> 
                <li><a href="Submenu2c.htm">Submenu2c</a></li>
                </ul> 
        </li> 
        <li><a href="Submenu2.htm">Submenu2</a></li> 
        </ul> 
</li>

<li><a href="Main2.htm">Main2</a></li> 
<li><a href="Main3.htm">Main3</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
        float: left;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:11px;
        overflow: hidden;
}

#nav ul {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        list-style:none;
}

#nav ul li {
        float:left;
}

#nav ul li a {
    float: left;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 11px 21px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset, 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;

}

#nav li ul {
        background:#C3C4BE;
        left: -999em;
        margin: 35px 0 0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        z-index: 9999;
}

#nav li ul a {
        background: none;
        border: 0 none;
        margin-right: 0;
        width: 160px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

#nav ul li a:hover,
#nav ul li:hover > a {
    color: #252525;
    background-color: #C3C4BE;
}

#nav li ul a:hover, 
#nav ul li li:hover > a  {
    color: #252525;
        background: #FFFFFF;

}



#nav li:hover ul {
        left: auto;
}


#nav li li ul {
        margin: -1px 0 0 160px;
        visibility:hidden;
}

#nav li li:hover ul {
        visibility:visible;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!  Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe you have compatibility mode enabled on the server for IE?

Comment: Good thought, but it's not enabled.  Also just tried this on a different PC, just to be sure and I get the same result - only in IE.

Comment: What version of IE? I dropped your code into [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ptk7r6m/), and I don't see any difference from IE9 and up. Fiddle seems to crap out in IE8 mode so I don't know about that one

Comment: Both PC's i've checked have been IE 11

Comment: I'm using IE11, and everything looks fine in that fiddle...does the fiddle display correctly for you? If not, what is your emulation mode set to in the dev tools?

Comment: Yeah, believe it or not it displays just fine for me there.  It's almost like its a issue viewing this over a network drive.